# contenteditable span does not work in .sortable <li>, but does outside of <li> - firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Using firefox, contenteditable="true" does not seem to work in an li that's sortable using the .sortable ui plugin.

Html:

```
<p id="hello" contenteditable="true">this is editable</p>
<ul>
  <li><span contenteditable="true">this is not</span></li>
  <li><span contenteditable="true">neither is this</span></li>      
</ul>
```

Js:

```
$("ul").sortable();
```

You can edit the first `<p>`, but not any of the `<span>`'s in the `<li>`'s.  This is in Firefox.  It works in Chrome.

Any ideas?

All this code is also here: http://jsbin.com/onosir/2/edit

Comment: It's not working in my chrome unless I click on the white space in between the list item icon and the actual text.  If I click on the text directly, no joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content in the spans can be edited, once they get focus. It's probably the sortable's mousedown method that won't allow the spans to get focus. Try using a handle for these cases.